# Arrow related error when pushing dataset to Hugging-face hub

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

i have quite a problem with my dataset:

The (future) dataset is a pandas dataframe that i loaded from a pickle file, the pandas dataset behaves correctly. My code is:

```
dataset.from_pandas(df)
dataset.push_to_hub("username/my_dataset", private=True)
```

because I thought it was pandas fault I also tried:

```
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(df_sentences.to_dict(orient='list'))
dataset.push_to_hub("username/my_dataset", private=True)
```

and to load it from file.

The error I get is:

> ArrowNotImplementedError: Unhandled type for Arrow to Parquet schema conversion: string

My dataset is composed by 4 columns of type string and one of ints, around 3600 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a reproducible sample, it is hard to test it, but one option is to convert data to `string[pyarrow]` dtype:

```py
dtypes = {
'column_a': 'string[pyarrow]',
'col_b': 'string[pyarrow]',
...
}

df_converted = df.astype(dtypes)
# proceed with the push
```

If possible, I would also upgrade to the latest versions, esp. for `pyarrow` and `pandas`.

Comment: I had this problem with BigQuery, it was indeed the column types.

Comment: @razimbres what was the problem in your case? I tried forcing in pandas the dtype, I also checked if there was any nan or similar but got 0

Comment: In my case the problem was the date. I applied 'pd.to_datetime(df.Date)' and it messed the pyarrow config. When I removed that, it worked.